# Windows Select API on OpenSSL

Tags: windows, select, openssl

I have a requirement, where my server(Windows C++ using OpenSSL) will listen to 'n' number of clients and responds asynchronously based on the client request. For this, I am planning to use the SELECT API call. But it seems that OpenSSL doesn't work with the SELECT API call. So just wondering whether any other method is there, through which I can achieve this functionality.

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSL works with `select()`, but the trick is knowing **WHEN** to use `select()`. For instance, traditional non-blocking socket logic when reading data is to call `select()` first and then call `recv()` when `select()` says there is data to read. That does NOT work with the tradtional OpenSSL API!  You need to call `ssl_read()` first and then call `select()` to wait for *readibility* only when `ssl_read()` reports an `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` error.  In other words, it is the difference between **wait-for-ready-then-act** vs **act-then-wait-for-ready**, respectively.  And there is the possibility that `ssl_read()` can report a `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` error, in which case you have to call `select()` to check for *writability* instead.  Yes, a read action can trigger a write action!

Similar consideration is needed for `ssl_send()` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` for writing, and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` for reading.  Yes, a write action can trigger a read action!

You really cannot graft tradtional OpenSSL on top of an existing non-SSL socket implementation, at least not without extra work.  It *can* be done (I've done it), but it is not easy. Tradtional OpenSSL has its own logistics that are almost backwards then traditional socket logic.

If you have an existing socket implementation and just want to add SSL/TLS to it without big headaches, you have two choices:

1. Use OpenSSL's BIO API instead.  Create two memory BIO pairs, one for input, and one for output.
2. Switch to Microsoft's Crypto/SChannel API (or another third party library that supports push models).

Either approach allows you to use your own socket I/O. When receiving encrypted data, read the socket data however you want and push it into the crypto engine, and when it spits out decrypted data then process as needed.  When sending unencrypted data, push it into the crypto engine, and when it spits out encrypted data then send it to the socket however you want.  This leaves you in full control of the socket.  Using the traditional OpenSSL API, OpenSSL takes over control of the socket.